# How to delete string if it contains specific character using regex in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a loop that reads in each line of a file. In the loop I want to have a regex that tests the line for a specific character and if the line contains that character I want to delete that whole line. I am very new to perl regex and I can't seem to figure out how to put one together.

Comment: It's not that you want to delete that line, its that you want to re-write the file without the line.

Comment: @sln O ok, Im planning on saving the new lines into an array.

Comment: You could use grep then.

Comment: @sln how is that implemented?

Comment: Do a search for grep and Perl.

Comment: @Tyler Did you try perl one liner?

Answer (score -1):

```
$ echo -e 'aa\nbb\nab\ncc' | 
  perl -e 'while (<>) { push @lines, $_ unless m/a/ } END { print @lines }'        
bb
cc
```

The push is inside a loop where `$_` is set to each subsequent line.  It appends the array `@lines` unless the given regular expression matches against `$_`.